# Parser error in ASP.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following the tutorial from this site [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3). Everything was going fine until I added the css and image folder. after adding these two things and running my project, I got the following error:

[image: ErrorImage]. I have two controller classes and one view class. If you guys want, I can share them with you. But if you also click on the link I provided, you can see the code there as well. Thanks for your time and help.

Here's my global.asax file:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    namespace MvcMovieStore
    {
        // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
        // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

        public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
            {
                filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            }

            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );

            }

            protected void Application_Start()
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

                // Use LocalDB for Entity Framework by default
                Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

                RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: You probably have a build error in VS.

Comment: Nope,I built the solution and its successful

Comment: @SLaks,I did that and it was succesful.

Answer (score 1):

check the code-behind file, global.asax.cs, the namespace should be MvcMovieStore, and the class name should be MvcApplication, I guess the class name doesn't match.

Comment: can you tell me where to make changes in my global file? I have posted it.

Comment: it looks correct, try to close the VS, reopen it, sometimes it just happens

Answer (score 0):

THis is wiered but I did not do anything, I simply ran it again and it worked. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for no particular reason.  Simply close and re-open Visual Studio has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the Namespace on the project, without refactoring that across the whole solution was my problem. Check your project Properties and see what your namespace is, ensure that lines up, across the board.